# Create lag numbers upto unique values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df, where I need to have the lag values to get the difference between times

```
df
ColA      ColB     Lag(ColB)
1      11:00:12    11:00:13
1      11:00:13    11:00:14
1      11:00:14       NA
2      11:00:15    11:00:16
2      11:00:16    11:00:17
2      11:00:17       NA
3      11:00:18    11:00:19
3      11:00:19    11:00:20
3      11:00:20       NA
```

Above only upto unique values I need to create a lag. If you see, the moment ColA changes from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3, the lag is NA. So Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: There is also `diff.difftime()`

Comment: Thanks. But I need to stop when colA changes. Like the one I mentioned in my question

Comment: yeah...so group by `colA`...

Comment: Is it like this ````df<- df %>% group_by(ColA) %>% summarise(NewCol = c(diff.difftime(x = df$ColB),NA))````

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Sotos, you need to group by your `colA` before doing the lag column and then calculate the diff time.

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages, you can calculate diff time by group

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% group_by(ColA) %>% mutate(NewLag = lead(ColB)) %>%
  mutate(diff = hms(NewLag)-hms(ColB))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ColA [3]
   ColA ColB     `Lag(ColB)` NewLag    diff
  <int> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 11:00:12 11:00:13    11:00:13     1
2     1 11:00:13 11:00:14    11:00:14     1
3     1 11:00:14 NA          NA          NA
4     2 11:00:15 11:00:16    11:00:16     1
5     2 11:00:16 11:00:17    11:00:17     1
6     2 11:00:17 NA          NA          NA
7     3 11:00:18 11:00:19    11:00:19     1
8     3 11:00:19 11:00:20    11:00:20     1
9     3 11:00:20 NA          NA          NA
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

**Example Data**

```r
structure(list(ColA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    ColB = c("11:00:12", "11:00:13", "11:00:14", "11:00:15", 
    "11:00:16", "11:00:17", "11:00:18", "11:00:19", "11:00:20"
    ), `Lag(ColB)` = c("11:00:13", "11:00:14", NA, "11:00:16", 
    "11:00:17", NA, "11:00:19", "11:00:20", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5569bf9b0310>)
```